# How to solve the issue of malformed node or string error in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, error-handling, python-dedupe

Here I have this dataframe and I am trying to remove the duplicate elements from each array in column 2 as follows and resultant array in Column 3.

```
Column1    Column 2                                                      Column3
0        [ABC|QWER|12345, ABC|QWER|12345]                         [ABC|QWER|12345] 
1        [TBC|WERT|567890,TBC|WERT|567890]                        [TBC|WERT|567890]
2        [ERT|TYIO|9845366, ERT|TYIO|9845366,ERT|TYIO|5]   [ERT|TYIO|9845366, ERT|TYIO|5]
3        NaN                                               NaN
4        [SAR|QWPO|34564557,SAR|QWPO|3456455]             [SAR|QWPO|34564557,SAR|QWPO|3456455]
5        NaN                                              NaN
6        [SE|WERT|12233412]                                [SE|WERT|12233412]
7        NaN                                               NaN
```

I m using following codes but its showing the error of  malformed node or string.Please help to solve this.

```
import ast
    def ddpe(a):
    return list(dict.fromkeys(ast.literal_eval(a)))

  df['column3'] = df['column2'].apply(ddpe)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming the values of 'column2' are strings since you are trying to use `ast.literal_eval`. In that case, try this instead

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def ddpe(str_val):
    if pd.isna(str_val):  # return NaN if value is NaN
        return np.nan  
    # Remove the square brackets, split on ',' and strip possible
    # whitespaces between elements   
    vals = [v.strip() for v in str_val.strip('[]').split(',')]
    # remove duplicates keeping the original order
    return list(dict.fromkeys(vals))

df['column3'] = df['column2'].apply(ddpe)
```

If the column values are lists already, you just need

```
def ddpe(lst_val):
    # return NaN is value is not a list. 
    # Assuming those are only the two options.
    if not isinstance(lst_val, list):   
        return np.nan  
    return list(dict.fromkeys(lst_val))

df['column3'] = df['column2'].apply(ddpe)
```

Comment: Hey,its giving the error ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @Cuckoo are the values lists or string representations of lists? I'm assuming the latter, as your solution attempt suggests by using  `ast.literal_eval`. However, the error suggests the values are lists. This type of information should be very clear in the post description to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: So,its like I concatenated few columns of dataset to get column2 and its dtype is object.Sorry for misuderstanding

Comment: @Cuckoo I updated the answer with the two cases. Does it work now?

Comment: @Cuckoo I meant the data type of the elements themselves. Are they strings or lists? For instance, what is the output of `df['column2'].map(type).unique()`?

Comment: array([<class 'list'>, <class 'float'>], dtype=object)  hey,its output is this and thanks that's working.

Comment: Also would be great if you could add few links for the better understanding as I m novice to this field.Thanks

Comment: @Cuckoo That means the element are lists as I suspected (the float comes from the fact the NaNs are floats). You're welcome, I'm glad it worked! Do you want resources to learn `pandas`?  I highly recommend the [official guides](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) of the documentation.